# Only matching when a string contains ALL characters specified in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a simple validator that will match John@gmail.com but not John@gmailcom or Johngmail.com - it must contain both *@ and .*

I am using this - `/[@.]/g` but it matches and tests when only one of these characters are matched.

Is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: Not the final solution, but one step closer : `^[John@gmail.com]{14}$` (I assumed chars can be shuffled because else that would be a strict equality withtout the neeed of a regexp)

Comment: positive lookahead [`/(?=.*@.*\.).+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/UNgypY/1)

Comment: If '@' followed by dot is the only check you perform for valid e-mail, `@.` happen to be valid e-mail either.

Comment: @UlysseBN  I can admit it's only a partial answer but how is that friendly or unfriendly ? By the way, when I talk about what I see, you talk about what you assume is in the mind of someone else, please check yourself about friendlyness.

Comment: @challet I'm really confused. I definitely thought your comment was ment as a joke, seeing that you forced the check on _any character included in `John@gmail.com`, fourteen times_, when OP was only talking about `@` and `.`. And your explanation wasn't there as well. I'll just remove my comment, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @UlysseBN I think I misunderstood a lot of things as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your regexp is that `[]` will tell whether *one of* `@` or `.` is present.

If order matters, and you want `@` to preceed `.`, you could use:

```
@.*\.
```

This will match any string that has `@` and `.` with any character between them.

If order doesn't matter, I guess there is really no need for a Regexp:

```js
myString.includes('@') && myString.includes('.')
```

The regexp version [is available on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FJfzx1/2/) so you can see details.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you are definitely right, and I guess it would be hard for a regexp to not care about order. Except with a trick like sorting the string before. I'll just delete this bit :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you should read again my answer... OP didn't ask for `@` to preceed `.`, hence my proposition is saying **if order matters** and **if order doesn't matter**. If OP wanted a real email validation, there are a lot more parameters to take into account anyway.

Comment: @UlysseBN- thanks, totally fixed the issue. Basic error from my end! Has to be a regex I think as I'm using data from an external source that will change, so for futureproofing it needs to handle more then just emails. After implementing what you suggested it now works on other stuff too. Thanks!